# how to remove a character from a paragraph in c?

Tags: c

I have written a c program which removes a character from a string, not from multiple lines then I write code to store multiple lines of a string but when I am compiling my code, I am not able to get proper output. Please, somebody, have a look.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char inputString[1000], ch, outputString[1000];

    int i,j=0;

    printf ("Enter a multi line string:\n");
    scanf ("%[^;]s", inputString);
    gets(inputString);

    printf ("Enter a letter to be removed:\n");
    scanf ("%c", &ch);
    for (i=0; inputString[i]!='\0';i++)
    {
        if(inputString[i]==ch)
        {
            outputString[j]=inputString[i+1];
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            outputString[j]=inputString[i];
        }
        j++;
    }
    for (i=0;i<j;i++)
    {
        printf ("%c", outputString[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: side note DONT USE 'gets' its not safe

Comment: then what i should use?

Comment: " I am not able to get proper output"... please post your actual input, your actual output and the desired output.

Comment: consider null-terminating your output string and using %s to printf

Comment: you  can use fgets(string,size,stdin);
but i don't really see the use of the gets after you read the input using scanf

Comment: as i will give any para containing more than two lines, then after removing a character from that para i want to get remaining lines of that para except that para..

Comment: okk i am trying.. thank you!

Comment: @RudraPratapSingh you already accepted my answer, however I edited it to add a proposal

Comment: sorry, i thing your edited ans can see everyone....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems in your program

1) With

```
scanf ("%[^;]s", inputString);
gets(inputString);
```

you rewrite *inputString* with the gets after the *scanf*, for instance if the input is `foo bar loop;` you set *inputString* with `foo bar loop` then you set it again with `;` so you lost all you got with *scanf*

2) Both *scanf* and *gets* can write out of *inputString*, you do not have any protection, the max size to read can be given to *scanf* and you can replace the use of *gets* by *fgets* (forgetting the fact you rewrite in *inputString*)

3) you never take into account the EOF case, always supposing something is enter

4) In

```
    if(inputString[i]==ch)
    {
        outputString[j]=inputString[i+1];
        i++;
    }
    else
    {
        outputString[j]=inputString[i];
    }
    j++;
```

`outputString[j]=inputString[i+1];` supposes you never have two consecutive times the character to remove, that way to do is wrong.

5) To use fixed size of array is not mandatory, allocate array then *realloc* when needed

6) In

```
for (i=0;i<j;i++)
{
    printf ("%c", outputString[i]);
}
```

better to end *outputString* with a null character to just print by *fputs* or *puts* to add a final \n in case it is missing

---

Here a proposal :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
  char * inputString = NULL;
  size_t sz = 0, used = 0;
  int v;

  printf ("Enter a multi line string (ended by ';'):\n");

  while ((v = getchar()) != ';') {
    if (v == EOF) {
      puts("premature EOF, abort");
      return -1;
    }

    if (used == sz) {
      sz += 100;
      inputString = realloc(inputString, sz);
      if (inputString == NULL) {
        puts("not enough memory");
        return -1;
      }
    }
    inputString[used++] = v;
  }

  /* read up to end of line */
  char * outputString = 0;

  if (getline(&outputString, &sz, stdin) == -1) {
    puts("premature EOF or not enough memory");
    return -1;
  }
  free(outputString);

  printf ("Enter a letter to be removed:\n");

  char ch;

  if (scanf ("%c", &ch) != 1) {
     puts("premature EOF, abort");
     return -1;
  }

  size_t i, j = 0;

  outputString = malloc(used + 1); /* worst case, +1 to have place for null character */

  for (i = 0; i != used; ++i)
  {
    if (inputString[i] != ch)
      outputString[j++] = inputString[i];
  }
  outputString[j] = 0;

  puts(outputString);

  free(inputString);
  free(outputString);

  return 0;
}
```

Compilation and execution:

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -pedantic -Wextra -g l.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
Enter a multi line string (ended by ';'):
this is a paragraph
  terminated by
a ;!!
Enter a letter to be removed:
i
ths s a paragraph
  termnated by
a
```

Execution under *valgrind* :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ valgrind ./a.out
==3900== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==3900== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==3900== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==3900== Command: ./a.out
==3900== 
Enter a multi line string (ended by ';'):
this is a paragraph
  terminated by
a ;!!
Enter a letter to be removed:
i
ths s a paragraph
  termnated by
a 
==3900== 
==3900== HEAP SUMMARY:
==3900==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3900==   total heap usage: 5 allocs, 5 frees, 2,307 bytes allocated
==3900== 
==3900== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==3900== 
==3900== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==3900== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 6 from 3)
```